# R - model.frame() and non-standard evaluation

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I am puzzled at a behaviour of a function that I am trying to write. My example comes from the `survival` package but I think that the question is more general than that. Basically, the following code

```
library(survival)
data(bladder)  ## this will load "bladder", "bladder1" and "bladder2"

mod_init <- coxph(Surv(start, stop, event) ~ rx + number, data = bladder2, method = "breslow")
survfit(mod_init)
```

Will yield an object that I am interested in. However, when I write it in a function,

```
my_function <- function(formula, data) {
  mod_init <- coxph(formula = formula, data = data, method = "breslow")
  survfit(mod_init)
  }

my_function(Surv(start, stop, event) ~ rx + number, data = bladder2)
```

the function will return an error at the last line:

```
 Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : 
  invalid 'envir' argument of type 'closure' 
10 eval(predvars, data, env) 
9 model.frame.default(formula = Surv(start, stop, event) ~ rx + 
    number, data = data) 
8 stats::model.frame(formula = Surv(start, stop, event) ~ rx + 
    number, data = data) 
7 eval(expr, envir, enclos) 
6 eval(temp, environment(formula$terms), parent.frame()) 
5 model.frame.coxph(object) 
4 stats::model.frame(object) 
3 survfit.coxph(mod_init) 
2 survfit(mod_init) 
1 my_function(Surv(start, stop, event) ~ rx + number, data = bladder2)
```

I am curious whether there is something obvious that I am missing or whether such behaviour is normal. I find it strange, since in the environment of `my_function` I would have the same objects as in the global environment when running the first portion of the code.

Edit: I also received useful input from Terry Therneau, the author of the `survival` package. This is his answer:

*This is a problem that stems from the non-standard evaluation done by model.frame.  The only way out of it that I have found is to add model.frame=TRUE to the original coxph call.  I consider it a serious design flaw in R.  Non-standard evaluation is like the dark side -- a tempting and easy path that always ends badly.
Terry T.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Diagnose**

From the error message:

```
2 survfit(mod_init, newdata = base_case)
1 my_function(Surv(start, stop, event) ~ rx + number, data = bladder2)
```

the problem is clearly not with `coxph` during model fitting, but with `survfit`.

And from this message:

```
10 eval(predvars, data, env) 
 9 model.frame.default(formula = Surv(start, stop, event) ~ rx + 
     number, data = data)
```

I can tell that the problem is that during early stage of `survfit`, the function `model.frame.default()` can not find a **model frame** containing relevant data used in formula `Surv(start, stop, event) ~ rx + number`. Hence it complains.

---

**What is a model frame?**

A model frame, is formed from the `data` argument passed to fitting routine, like `lm()`, `glm()` and `mgcv:::gam()`. It is a data frame with the same number of rows as `data`, but:

- dropping all variables not referenced by `formula`
- adding many attributes, the most important of which is `envrionement`

Most model fitting routines, like `lm()`, `glm()`, and `mgcv:::gam()`, will keep the model frame in their fitted object by default. This has advantage that if we later call `predict`, and no `newdata` is provided, it will find data from this model frame for evaluation. However, a clear disadvantage is that it will substantially increase the size of your fitted object.

However, `survival:::coxph()` is an exception. It will by default **not** retain such model frame in their fitted object. Well, clearly, this makes the resulting fitted object much smaller in size, but, expose you to the problem you have encountered. **If we want to ask `survival:::coxph()` to keep this model frame, then use `model = TRUE` of this function.**

---

**Test with `survial:::coxph()`**

```
library(survival); data(bladder)

my_function <- function(myformula, mydata, keep.mf = TRUE) {
  fit <- coxph(myformula, mydata, method = "breslow", model = keep.mf)
  survfit(fit)
  }
```

Now, this function call will fail, as you have seen:

```
my_function(Surv(start, stop, event) ~ rx + number, bladder2, keep.mf = FALSE)
```

but this function call will succeed:

```
my_function(Surv(start, stop, event) ~ rx + number, bladder2, keep.mf = TRUE)
```

---

**Same behaviour for `lm()`**

We can actually demonstrate the same behaviour in `lm()`:

```
## generate some toy data
foo <- data.frame(x = seq(0, 1, length = 20), y = seq(0, 1, length = 20) + rnorm(20, 0, 0.15))

## a wrapper function
bar <- function(myformula, mydata, keep.mf = TRUE) {
  fit <- lm(myformula, mydata, model = keep.mf)
  predict.lm(fit)
  }
```

Now this will succeed, by keeping model frame:

```
bar(y ~ x - 1, foo, keep.mf = TRUE)
```

while this will fail, by discarding model frame:

```
bar(y ~ x - 1, foo, keep.mf = FALSE)
```

---

**Using argument `newdata`?**

Note that my example for `lm()` is slightly artificial, because we can actually use `newdata` argument in `predict.lm()` to get through this problem:

```
bar1 <- function(myformula, mydata, keep.mf = TRUE) {
  fit <- lm(myformula, mydata, model = keep.mf)
  predict.lm(fit, newdata = lapply(mydata, mean))
  }
```

Now whether we keep model frame, both will succeed:

```
bar1(y ~ x - 1, foo, keep.mf = TRUE)
bar1(y ~ x - 1, foo, keep.mf = FALSE)
```

Then you may wonder: can we do the same for `survfit()`?

`survfit()` is a generic function, in your code, you are really calling `survfit.coxph()`. There is indeed a `newdata` argument for this function. The documentation reads:

> newdata:
>
> a data frame with the same variable names as those that appear in the 
>     ‘coxph’ formula. ... ... Default is the mean of the covariates used in the 
>     ‘coxph’ fit.

So, let's try:

```
my_function1 <- function(myformula, mydata) {
  mtrace.off()
  fit <- coxph(myformula, mydata, method = "breslow")
  survival:::survfit.coxph(fit, newdata = lapply(mydata, mean))
  }
```

and we hope this work:

```
my_function1(Surv(start, stop, event) ~ rx + number, bladder2)
```

But:

```
Error in is.data.frame(data) (from #5) : object 'mydata' not found

1: my_function1(Surv(start, stop, event) ~ rx + number, bladder2)
2: #5: survival:::survfit.coxph(fit, lapply(mydata, mean))
3: stats::model.frame(object)
4: model.frame.coxph(object)
5: eval(temp, environment(formula$terms), parent.frame())
6: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
7: stats::model.frame(formula = Surv(start, stop, event) ~ rx + number, data =
8: model.frame.default(formula = Surv(start, stop, event) ~ rx + number, data 
9: is.data.frame(data)
```

Note that although we pass in `newdata`, it is not used in construction of model frame:

```
3: stats::model.frame(object)
```

Only `object`, a copy of fitted model, is passed to `model.frame.default()`.

This is very different from what happens in `predict.lm()`, `predict.glm()` and `mgcv:::predict.gam()`. In these routines, `newdata` is passed to `model.frame.default()`. For example, in `lm()`, there is:

```
m <- model.frame(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels)
```

I don't use `survival` package, so not sure how `newdata` works in this package. So I think we really need some expert explaining this.

Comment: Thank you for your very clear explanation.
One thing is bothering me though: why does that work in interactive use then (outside the function) ?

Comment: Thank you for this very thorough and perfect explanation for the problem I was having today. 

Answer (score -2):

I think it might be that if your

```
Surv(start, stop, event) ~ rx + number
```

is in as a parameter, it does not get properly created. Try put

```
is.Surv(formula)
```

as your first line in the function. I suspect it wont work, then I would suggest using apply family of functions.

Comment: It seems that the formula is loaded properly even when passed as an argument. That is why the Cox model actually works. The error only comes at the survfit() because of some scoping rule I guess.