# Does `lm` return `model` for reasons other than `predict`

Tags: r, memory, lm

`lm` sets `model = TRUE` by default, meaning the entire dataset used for learning is copied and returned with the fitted object. This is used by `predict` but creates memory overhead (example below).

I am wondering, is the copied dataset used for any reason other than `predict`?

Not essential to answer, but I'd also like to know of models that store data for reasons other than `predict`.

#### Example

```
object.size(lm(mpg ~ ., mtcars))
#> 45768 bytes
object.size(lm(mpg ~ ., mtcars, model = FALSE))
#> 28152 bytes
```

Bigger dataset = bigger overhead.

#### Motivation

To share my motivation, the [twidlr](https://github.com/drsimonj/twidlr) package forces users to provide data when using `predict`. If this makes copying the dataset when learning unnecessary, it seems reasonable to save memory by defaulting to `model = FALSE`. I've opened a relevant issue [here](https://github.com/drsimonj/twidlr/issues/27).

A secondary motivation - you can easily fit many models like `lm` with [pipelearner](https://github.com/drsimonj/pipelearner), but copying data each time creates massive overhead. So finding ways to cut down memory needs would be very handy!

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but the data.frame can sometimes be helpful in determining characteristics of the data that the model was created from. For example, if you fit a model like this`lm(mpg ~ drat^2, data=mtcars)`, the data.frame will give you the actual values of `mpg` and `drat` whereas otherwise you wouldn't know anything about the distribution of `drat` and whether it might take on positive or negative values because of the transformation that squares the data.

Comment: If I know the distribution from the data.frame, I have a better idea of whether I'm interpolating or extrapolating from the model when making new predictions.

Comment: Thanks @StevenMortimer. Although it's not exactly what I'm after, I agree it's important to know properties of the data. However, I tend to do this prior to modeling rather than fitting the model then examining the copied data.

Comment: Yep, true, but sometimes you'll end up with somebody else's model and the original data is lost or not accessible for your examination.

Comment: To me, it's not frequent enough to warrant storing the data (especially when you may be fitting 1000s of models &/or based on large data sets), but I see your point. I'd hope that people document fitted models properly if passing them around like that. Another reason for my question is that many models other than `lm` point to, rather than copy the data. eg, see https://gist.github.com/drsimonj/5b2cfc428fce350676db5dc77c059052

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think model frame is returned as a protection against non-standard evaluation.

Let's look at a small example.

```
dat <- data.frame(x = runif(10), y = rnorm(10))
FIT <- lm(y ~ x, data = dat)
fit <- FIT; fit$model <- NULL
```

What is the difference between

```
model.frame(FIT)
model.frame(fit)
```

?? Checking `methods(model.frame)` and `stats:::model.frame.lm` shows that in the first case, model frame is efficiently extracted from `FIT$model`; while in the second case, it will be reconstructed from `fit$call` and `model.frame.default`. Such difference also results in the difference between

```
# depends on `model.frame`
model.matrix(FIT)
model.matrix(fit)
```

as model matrix is built from a model frame. If we dig further, we will see that these are different, too,

```
# depends on `model.matrix`
predict(FIT)
predict(fit)

# depends on `predict.lm`
plot(FIT)
plot(fit)
```

Note that this is where the problem could be. If we deliberately remove `dat`, we can not reconstruct the model frame, then all these will fail:

```
rm(dat)
model.frame(fit)
model.matrix(fit)
predict(fit)
plot(fit)
```

while using `FIT` will work.

---

This is not bad enough. The following example under non-standard evaluation is really bad!

```
fitting <- function (myformula, mydata, keep.mf = FALSE) {
  b <- lm(formula = myformula, data = mydata, model = keep.mf)
  par(mfrow = c(2,2))
  plot(b)
  predict(b)
  }
```

Now let's create a data frame again (we have removed it earlier)

```
dat <- data.frame(x = runif(10), y = rnorm(10))
```

Can you see that

```
fitting(y ~ x, dat, keep.mf = TRUE)
```

works but

```
fitting(y ~ x, dat, keep.mf = FALSE)
```

fails?

Here is a question I answered / investigated a year ago: [R - model.frame() and non-standard evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37364571/4891738) It was asked for `survival` package. That example is really extreme: even if we provide `newdata`, we would still get error. Retaining the model frame is the only way to proceed!

---

Finally on your observation of memory costs. In fact, `$model` is not mainly responsible for potentially large `lm` object. `$qr` is, as it has the same dimension with model matrix. Consider a model with lots of factors, or nonlinear terms like `bs`, `ns` or `poly`, the model frame is much smaller compared with model matrix. So omitting model frame return does not help reduce `lm` object size. This is actually one motivation that `biglm` is developed.

---

Since I inevitably mentioned `biglm`, I would emphasis again that this method only helps reducing the final model object size, not RAM usage during model fitting.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks. From your answer, I see `plot` being a problem. Also, I had noticed qr taking up memory, but I think it's necessary to make predictions (whereas model frame is not)?